# write only specific lines from file a to file b

Tags: python, string, file, new-operator

I have problems writing only lines of interest to a new file.

f1 file is composed by raws with the following content:

```
line =
'Raw,512561008,58913000000,,,-1226439751087359050,0.0,6.748478024207768,,,0,14,0.0,16397,510195928489024,10,33.76073455810547,91.65148631320972,0.0037611895240843296,1,6907.217495186118,0.0018805947620421648,1.56109798E9,,,,0,,5,,1.56109798E9'
```

I am interested to write lines that do not have '5' as value between indexes [-15:-14]. I have wrote the following function but when I run it the new file still contains the unwanted lines. I would appreciate if someone can point out what am I doing wrong. Thank you!.

```
def CleanGNSSLogger(ASCIIfileName,filterStr=None):
   try:
      with open(ASCIIfileName, 'r') as f1, open(ASCIIfileName[:-4]+'_clean'+ASCIIfileName[-4:],'w') as f2:
          for line in f1:
              if line[-15:-14] != '5':
                  f2.write(line)
   except IOError as e:
      print ('Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror)

   return
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to point filter value: ,,,,0,,`5`,,1.56109798E9 . But it looks like a csv file, so if the value not equals 1.56109798E9, your index will be wrong. You must read this file by csv lib.

Comment: It's very likely that it is so, that the number or expression you are looking for is not always in the same index. As @YangHG suggests, if it happens to be a 'csv' then you will know which column you will have to check to test the presence of your expression or value.

Comment: thanks guys, indeed I should have read by csv lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this, so you make sure the value (5) you are interested in is robustly accessible:

```
SOME_NAME_INDEX = 29 # or the correct location of the value of interest

def CleanGNSSLogger(ASCIIfileName,filterStr=None):
    try:
        with open(ASCIIfileName, 'r') as f1, open(ASCIIfileName[:-4]+'_clean'+ASCIIfileName[-4:],'w') as f2:
            for line in f1:
                values = line.split(",")
                if values[SOME_NAME_INDEX] != '5':
                    f2.write(line)
    except IOError as e:
        print ('Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for help. Following your suggestion I manage to write only the lines of interest into the new file :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if "5" not in line[-15:-14]:
```

See if this works.

Comment: it didn´t work in my original script. If I add your solution after I do line.split(","), it works. thanks :)